# Override properties in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to override some properties using Mongo Connect. I added row in `connect-distributed.properties` with

```
connector.client.config.override.policy=ALL
```

like in this tuttorial
https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_enlarge_the_maximum_size_of_the_message_delivered_to_kafka

but after add option `producer.override.max.request.size` in configuration, I catth

```
The 'None' policy does not allow 'max.request.size' to be overridden in the connector configuration.
```

what could be the mistake?

Comment: Did you restart the Connect cluster? Properties files are only read at startup

Comment: Yes. I use platform by Confluent. I changed file, restarted server, but caught exception

Comment: If you have correctly set the value, then the error shouldn't say you're using `'None' policy`

Answer (score 1):

In `connect-distributed.properties`, you need to configure `connector.client.config.override.policy` to `All` (lowercase L's)

Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration